# How to reset the command line back to factory settings?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, zsh

There are questions like this already. My problem is my command line is only reading the first word of every command. I know I did something to mess it up but I don't know what or how to reverse it. I'm very new, I'm using a MacBook Air intel and zsh.

I tried `mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile_backup`. The output is `zsh: command not found: mv`.

I think the terminal is only reading the first word. Also when I go to preferences and look for the terminal file to delete it, I don't see it. I have been stuck for days and can't even begin to code until this is fixed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: A command line is what you type into an interactive shell. There is no _factory setting_ to things **you** are typing.  I also don't understand why you are mentioning `.bash_profile`, which has no meaning with zsh anyway. I also don't know what a _terminal file_ possibly would be.

Comment: By and large, your question seems to be appropriate for [su] instead of [so], so I voted for closing it here. I suggest that you ask it again on  [su], describing everything you do (type, click and so on), and what effect you get, and what you instead expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

To reset your Zsh config to "factory defaults":

1. Open the Finder.
2. In the side bar, click your home folder (which has a house icon, followed by your username).
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to reveal hidden files.
4. Move all files starting with `.z` to another folder.
5. Open a new Terminal window/tab.

---

> The output is `zsh: command not found: mv`.

This means you've removed `/bin` from your `$path`. To fix this:

1. Look through your `.z*` files (which you moved to another folder, above) to find where you made this mistake.
2. Fix the mistake.
3. Put your `.z*` files back into your home folder.
4. Open a new Terminal window/tab.